# Java RMI Heartbeat time process loop

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi, heartbeat

I'm trying to implement an ID lock system that is managed by RMI. Pretty much, when a client enters an ID, it sends that ID along to the RMI server, which stores it in a list, along with the client ID, and a cycle counter.

The server, after 30 seconds, will increment all the cycle counters. Unless the client sends along an Unlock message, the client will send along a Heartbeat, which will update that cycle counter back to 0. If a cycle counter >= 3, then the server will assume the client has disconnected improperly and release the lock on the ID.

I've been researching online, and I found a great deal of very specific ways of doing this, but too many that seem too vague, or too specific to the one project's needs. I think I have a general idea of how to do this, but I want to get things straight:

**1 -**  Most implementations would have this "cycle update" logic happening in an endless loop on a separate thread. Is this correct? It just seems like my RMI server's Main class has very little going on, and that maybe I could implement the loop in there.

**2 -**  If indeed the thread is the right way to go, when do I launch the thread? Is there any special way that this needs to be accomplished? I've looked online and found many sites saying to use threads, but none showing a good example of where they execute the thread.

Thanks for any help you can provide. I'm still kind of green with RMI, so I thank you for your patience.

Comment: You should use the Unreferenced interface for part of this. It does the liveness checking for you.

Comment: I read up on the Unreference interface. Looks like it would only fire when there are no more clients connected to the server. I would need it to fire every time the server became de-referenced by any client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, your problem is that how to increment cyclic counters every 30 minutes, not about RMI.

if so, you may use ScheduledExecutorService.

there is a pseudo code below.

```
public class IdLockMgr {
  private Map<String, Integer> idToCycleMap = new HashMap<>();
  private ScheduledExecutorService service;
  public IdLockMgr() {
     service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
     //BAD
((ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor)service).setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(false);
     service.scheduleAtFixedRate(...);//this is point.
  }
  public void lockId(String id) {
    idToCycleMap.put(id, 0);
  }
  public void shutdown() {
     service.shutdown();
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, I had a couple ideas of how to implement a cyclic counter, but I didn't even know about `ScheduledExecutorService.` This could help with firing a process off on a background thread while the RMI does its own thing. Now, as for the question of "When to do this," should this service be kicked off after the server has been bound to the registry?